# Iterate through CSV and match lines with a specific date

Tags: python-3.x

I am parsing a CSV file into a list. Each list item will have a column list[3] which contains a date in the format: mm/dd/yyyy

I need to iterate through the file and extract only the rows which contain a specific date range.

for example, I want to extract all rows for the month of 12/2015. I am having trouble determining how to match the date. Any nudging in the right direction would be helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: checks column list[3]  mm matches 12 and yyyy matches 2015

Comment: Seeing some code, the csv, the output, anything would be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Method1:

splits your column to month, day and year, converts month and year to integers and then compare and match 12/2015

```
column3 = "12/31/2015"
month, day, year = column3.split("/")

if int(month) == 12 and int(year) == 2015:
    # do your thing
```

Method2:

parses a datetime string to time object and gets the attributes `tm_year` and `tm_mon`, compare them with corresponding month and year.

```
>>> import time
>>> to = time.strptime("12/03/2015", "%m/%d/%Y")
>>> to.tm_mon
12
>>> to.tm_year
2015
```

Comment: When using your second example, it crashes on the first row, which is the column names.